# iOS App starting in landscape mode on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

My App is designed to work on both portrait and landscape mode. 
If the App is started on portrait mode, everything works as expected. And you can rotate to any other orientation without problems.

But if started in landscape mode, unexpected things happen.
First: about a third of the right display does not react to touches. Any buttons on this side are not working.
Second: Change orientation to portrait mode will not update the screen correctly. The page layout remains the same as in landscape mode, but is rotated and centered. The right and left sides are cut off.

The problem seems to occur only on some user-devices. On my devices and on simulator everything is in order.

Comment: Can you isolate the problem to specific device version / iOS version? Also, are you using normal Objective-C / Swift to write your App (or 3rd party tools?)

Comment: iOS 8.x, Objective-C with Eclipse. In Simulator with iOS 8.1 OK. Until today, I had 2 reports from users with iPad Air and iPad Mini. Today I've got a new report with iPad Air and iPhone 6 Plus.

Comment: Objective-C with Eclipse ? That's weird. Use Xcode !

Comment: Sorry! Of course, I'm using Xcode, latest version.